# python: return list method takes index as arguments

Tags: python, list, function, methods, arguments

I'm wondering if something pseudo coded below is possible:

```
def getLst(index = :):    
    lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    return lst[index]


print getLst()
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

print getLst(2)
>> 3


print getLst(2:-2)
>> [3, 4, 5]
```

Obviously I'm getting a SyntaxError.

The method is being used in at class for returning a private list.

I know the example below is possible, and it might be more correctly (easier to read/understand the code), but since I've got the idea of doing the first example and it wasn't possible I got curioss of knowing how to make the first example work.

```
def getLst():    
    lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    return lst


print getLst()
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

print getLst()[2]
>> 3

print getLst()[2:-2]
>> [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: It'a not possible in functions header, instead you can pass start and end argument to your function.`getLst(start,end)`

Comment: `c[a:b]` if `c.index[a] == c.index[b]` or `c.index[a] > c.index[b]` you got  a `[ ]` answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `2:-2` notation is specific for array subscribtion (ie `a[2:-2]` expression). The closest thing you could do if you want to accept that notation is to actually use the whole notation. That could be done by overloading the `__getitem__` method (if you want negatives you need to overload `__len__` as well).

```
class GetList:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l

    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return self.l[x]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.l)
```

Actually `a[2:4]` is syntactic sugar for `a[slice(2,4,None)]`, and `a[2:-2]` is syntactic sugar for `a[slice(2,len(a)-2,None)]`. You then of course examine the `slice` by using `x.start`, `x.stop` and `x.step` (given that it's a slice of course) and do whatever you'd like based on that.

If you'd like you could use decorator to enable calling a function using subscribtion notation:

```
class subscrfunc:
    def __init__(self, f):
         self.f = f

    def __call__(self, x):
         return self.f(x)

    def __getitem__(self, x):
         return self.f(x)

    def __len__(self):
         return 0

@subscrfunc
def getLst(index):
    lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    retur lst[index]

getLst[2:3]
```

Note though that the hack allowing negative `stop` in the slice is to fake a length of zero which will result in `getLst[2:-2]` would result in the argument being `slice(2,-2,None)` which is nonsense to a list which will return nothing (instead you have to manually handle the case where one index is negative).

Comment: It seems like it is not possible to get it to work exactly how I wished for. But I think your reply is the best answer - and at least I've gained some experience using slice, __call__, __getitem__ and __len__.